# Preventing the repeat of given numbers in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Suppose you have an arraylist of 10 indexes including either the numbers 1, 2, or 3 only. I am trying to get these to print without repeating the same number consecutively if possible.

For example, arraylist includes the numbers {1,1,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,2}
I would like it to print as: {1,2,3,1,2,1,2,1,2,1}

Sorry if this can be done much simpler than what I am trying to do. I am still pretty new to programming.

```
    int j;
    int k;
    for (j=0; j<p.size()-1;j++)
    {
        for(k =1; k<p.size()-1;k++)
        {      
            if(p.get(k)==p.get(j))
            {
    //       Person temp = p.get(j);
    //       p.remove(j);
    //       p.add(temp);
            }        
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"I am trying to get these to print without repeating the same number"*  Why?  What is doing so supposed to achieve?

Comment: What if your arraylist of 10 indexes gets 1's? What is the expected output in that case?

Comment: @sampson-chen  Good point.  I don't think this requirement has been carefully thought through.

Comment: Your sample output has almost no correlation with the input.

Comment: its the input sorted in a way that results in numbers being most spread out (kinda like an antisort for biggest entropy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not just that.. Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (!list.get(i+1).equals(list.get(i)) {
        System.out.print (list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: That logic would result in something like.  `{1,2,1,2,3,1,2}`

Comment: Well, that's what he wanted, considering his question info. He doesn't want to have just 1,2,3. Set wouldn't work. I have no idea, why he needs that logically, but still - look at the question one more time.

Comment: *"Well, that's what he wanted,.."*  Not as indicated by *"I would like it to print as: `{1,2,3,1,2,1,2,1,2,1}`"*.

Comment: Yeah, just noticed the "logic", lol. Then the solution would be to use HashSets in a Cycle, by printing the current Set and then removing those numbers as "List from the Set" from the root List. That is going to be freaking legacy code...

Comment: Sorry, let me clear this up. As long as the same numbers don't repeat, it is fine. It doesn't have to be in an an ascending order while at the same time not repeating.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to print the numbers without printing the same number more than once consecutively, if possible.

Here's a simple algorithm that comes closest to what you are asking for (prefer ascending ordering, avoid repeat of same number twice in a row if possible)  It may not cover all assumptions, since the question has not defined all possible case:

1. Since elements in the arraylist can only be 1, 2, or 3, read each element in the arraylist first and count how many of each 1, 2, and 3 there are.
2. Use a variable to keep track of the previous number that you printed (initialize this as 3 at the start), loop until all counters are zero:

   - If the previous number is 3 and the count for 1 is > 0: Print 1, save 1 to "previous number", decrement the counter for 1.
   - Else if count for 1 == 0, try 2, and then 3
   - If the previous number is 1 and the count for 2 is > 0: Print 2, save 2 to "previous number", decrement the counter for 2.
   - Else if count for 2 == 0, try 3, and then 1
   - If the previous number is 2 and the count for 3 is > 0: Print 3, save 3 to "previous number", decrement the counter for 3
   - Else if count for 3 == 0, try 1, and then 2